# Flutter Permissions Handler Not Working Properly

Tags: flutter, permissions

I am trying to get the user's location from within my app by requesting for permission(shows dialog correctly) and navigating only if granted. Library being used `permission_handler` in flutter. I am unable to get the location widget from the settings tile menu to turn on and permission status from library is showing `permission.disabled`.

I have opened the settings tile programmatically for my app
and it's listed and active like below block:

```
void _requestPerms () async{
Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> statuses = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([
  PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse, PermissionGroup.locationAlways
]);
final status = statuses[PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse];
switch(status){
  case PermissionStatus.disabled:
    await PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
    break;
}
_updateStatus(status);
```

}

Can someone help me understand why despite getting the dialog prompt once, the phone location widget is not turning on and how to navigate to next route on condition of `permission granted` or exit the app gracefully if not. Thanks.

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:eme_clone/utils/styles.dart';
import 'package:eme_clone/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class LocationDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   _LocationDialogState createState() => _LocationDialogState();
  }

class _LocationDialogState extends State<LocationDialog> {

PermissionStatus _status;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse)
    .then(_updateStatus);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
debugPrint('Location Status $_status');
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('assets/images/perm_icon_location.png'),
          Text(
            locationDialogHeader,
            style: locationHeaderStyle,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Text(
              locationDialogBody,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: locationTextBodyStyle,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  onPressed: _requestPerms,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                    child: Text(
                      allow,
                      style: allowBtnTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )),
  );
}

void _updateStatus(PermissionStatus value) {
  setState(() {
    _status = value;
  });
}

void _requestPerms () async{
  Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> statuses = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([
  PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse, PermissionGroup.locationAlways
]);
  final status = statuses[PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse];
  switch(status){
    case PermissionStatus.disabled:
     await PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
     break;
  }
  _updateStatus(status);
}
```

}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the **full code**. It made the debug process faster.

First, you need to add the following to your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file. (Before  tag)

```
<!-- Permissions options for the `location` group -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Then, you can use the [flutter_spinkit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit) to build an initial loading screen while waiting for user permission. 
To exit the app if a user doesn't grant permission, use

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
```

To navigate to the next screen after the request is granted, checkout your modified **full code**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LocationDialog(),
    );
  }
}

class LocationDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationDialogState createState() => _LocationDialogState();
}

class _LocationDialogState extends State<LocationDialog>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  PermissionStatus _status;

  @override
  void initState() {
    runFirst();
    super.initState();
  }

  runFirst() async {


//await PermissionHandler()
//        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse)
//        .then(_updateStatus);

 /* PermissionHandle() deprecated in permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.3 */

 await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status.then(_updateStatus);

    await _requestPerms();
    if (_status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
    } else if (_status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SpinKitFadingCircle(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: index.isEven ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _requestPerms() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await 
        [
      Permission.locationWhenInUse,
      Permission.locationAlways
    ].request();



   if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.serviceStatus.isEnabled) {
        _updateStatus(PermissionStatus.enable);
        openAppSettings();
   }

  //  switch (status) {
  //    case PermissionStatus.disabled:
  //      await PermissionHandler().
  //      break;
  //  }
  //  _updateStatus(status);
  //  }

  void _updateStatus(PermissionStatus value) {
    setState(() {
      _status = value;
    });
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NextPageState createState() => _NextPageState();
}

class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> {
  PermissionStatus _status;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('Location Status $_status');
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('assets/images/perm_icon_location.png'),
          Text(
            "LocationDialogHelper",
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Text(
              "locationDialogBody",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  onPressed: _requestPerms,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "allow",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  void _requestPerms() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
            Permission.locationWhenInUse,
            Permission.locationAlways,
          ].request();

    final status = Permission.locationWhenInUse.serviceStatus;
    _updateStatus(status);

// switch (status) {
 //     case PermissionStatus.disabled:
 //       await PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
 //       break;
//    }
//    _updateStatus(status);
//  }

  void _updateStatus(PermissionStatus value) {
    setState(() {
      _status = value;
    });
  }
}
```

**Note:**

A lot of breaking changes with the   `permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.3`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What I'm trying to accomplish is show a dialog that has a button, pressed will request for permission, if true then next screen.                               I have tried your code but it shows a spinner and then crashes with this message - MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods).

Comment: It runs now without error but the main issue still remains which is I have to turn on the phone's location manually to get it to work and not from the developed app's permissions page. If I can get a solution for that, will help a lot

Comment: The type of popup you get depends on the phone and the API version it uses. On the Nexus 5 API 28 emulator, I get the grant permission directly in the app, while in my Samsung 7edge run oneUI, I get a popup redirecting me to the settings.
If you use the Nexus 5 emulator, you will see the behaviour you want.

 I checked the source code of permission_handler, and I saw no way to force the permission to be granted in the app for all devices.

Comment: I will accept your answer. Thank you for your efforts and desire to help others sir. God bless.

Comment: It is a pleasure!

Comment: After "flutter clean" its worked perfectly.. Thank you so much..

Comment: change `PermissionGroup` to `Permission`

Comment: change above code 
from 
"final status = Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;"
to 
"final status = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;"

Answer (score 0):

In Android 11 , we don't get any permission due to some issues. We can get it using this way.

1. Go to ***android/app/ build.gradle*** file . add this format of **defaultConfig** code

defaultConfig {

```
            applicationId com.example.storare_file_path
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 32
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
```

2. GO to the ***android/gradle.properties.***  add these code

   ```
           android.useAndroidX=true
           android.enableJetifier=true
   ```
3. Add the required permission in **android/src/ main/ androidManifest.xml** file.

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```